# Does pycharm or any other Python IDE have an __init__ generator?

Tags: python, pycharm, pydev, spyder

It seems feasible to have a feature that automates the task of generating a skeleton **init** routine for a new class.

One approach would be to write

```
Class C(object):
   __init__(self, a, b, c, ...):
```

then hit a key or invoke a menu function that adds the code

```
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        ...
```

The programmer could then modify the generated code to deal with computations around the initial parameters.

I recognize that there are introspective approaches that achieve a similar effect at runtime, but this deprives the IDE of the ability to prompt on class member names while entering other code.

Comment: Thanks to juanpa and @Daniyal for pointing me towards Templates, a feature of which I was unaware. Thanks especially to Daniyal for managing to quickly get in a more complete answer before discussion was cut off.

Mac users will find the function that Daniyal describes under Pycharm->Preferences rather than File->Settings.